# Heroku redirect for subdomain using AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Our domain example.com is hosted on GoDaddy. I've followed the links to migrate the aa.example.com subdomain to AWS Route 53.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53#nakedroot-domain

[Heroku redirect from example.com to www.example.com retaining HTTPS using AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53423092/heroku-redirect-from-example-com-to-www-example-com-retaining-https-using-aws)

1. Consider aa is an application which is running on Heroku.
2. Created a hosted zone for aa.example.com on Route53 and specified the NS entries in GoDaddy.
3. Created the S3 bucket with same name as hosted zone (bucket name - aa.example.com)
4. Update aa.example.com S3 bucket with this

   "Static website hosting" with

   "Target bucket or domain" => "www.aa.example.com"

   "protocol"  => "https"
5. Go to "aa.example.com" hosted zone created CNAME record to point Heroku DNS target (www.aa.example.com pointed it to Heroku DNS target)
6. Create A record alias point to S3 target

www.aa.example.com (is working)
Where as aa.example.com is not working?

Can somebody help me what is wrong in this step? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a cloudfront distribution for the domain aa.example.com
2. Specify the originid to S3 bucket (bucket name - aa.example.com)
3. Update Route53 hosted zone to point cloudfront distribution

This post help me to debug and fix my issue:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=241750